# Unable to (un)protect questions after editing the post inline

Tags: bug, protected-questions, inline-editor

A pretty minor issue; but a bug nonetheless. Steps to reproduce:

1. Acquire the [Protect Questions](/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege.
2. Go to any valid questions for protection (at least 1 day old and have an answer by <10 rep user) *or* questions that are already protected.
3. Use the *edit* button to enable inline editing.
4. Edit a little bit and save your edit.
5. Try clicking on the *(un)protect* link now. While the confirmation popup shows up, clicking on the button to confirm the action does nothing.

This is still an issue as of June 2020.